# Why am I getting error "unexpected token module" in shims-d.vue.ts?

Tags: eslint

I installed typescript together with eslint for the first time in a Vue.js project.
In shims-d.vue.ts I have word 'module' underlined and an error saying

> unexpected token module

This is my shims-d.vue.ts.

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import { defineComponent } from "vue";
  const Component: ReturnType<typeof defineComponent>;
  export default Component;
}
```

I found that if I add this line

```
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
```

to to .eslintrs.json, the error is supressed, but instead I'm getting errors in all components' first html tag:

Parsing error: Unterminated regular expression literal.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Same problem but different module name, I attached a screenshot https://i.imgur.com/fWh8Gnx.png